# Linetype can not be changed with element_line

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, themes

I want to create a plot with the following data as example:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

Data <- data.table(Datum = c("2017-11-01","2017-11-02","2017-11-03","2017-11-04","2017-11-05","2017-11-06","2017-11-07","2017-11-08","2017-11-09","2017-11-10"),Index = c(200,250,230,210,190,215,216,250,260,245), Long = c(c(250,220,225,215,240,255,256,266,223,222)))
Data$Datum <- as.Date(Data$Datum, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

startdate <- min(Data$Datum)
enddate <- max(Data$Datum)

plot <- ggplot(Data, aes(Datum)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Index, colour = "Index"), size = 0.5, alpha = 0.5) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = Long, colour = "Long"), size = 0.5, alpha = 0.5) + 
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white")) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(), panel.grid.major.y = element_line(size = 0.5, colour = "grey", linetype = "dotted")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,300,20)) + 
  scale_x_date(breaks = seq(as.Date(startdate), as.Date(enddate), by="2 month"), date_labels = "%m %Y") +
  ylab("") +
  xlab("")


plot <- ggplotly(plot)
print(plot)
```

[image: chart]

But as you can see in the graph, the linetype of the x grid is still solid, even if set with `linetype = "dotted"`

How can I change the linetype or what is wrong with my approach?

Comment: try `linetype = 3`

Comment: Hmm, It seems plotly package (or plot.ly itself?) has no ability to change linetype as I read the source...: https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/blob/f5dd6ae20d0e266f456777828349b76f0b19ab81/R/ggplotly.R#L703-L706 Maybe you should file an issue on the repo.

Comment: This gives some workarounds: http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/linetype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, it can be seen that the plot comes out as desired within ggplot, but loses the dashed lines once converted into plotly. As mentioned within the comments, this appears to be a limitation of [plotly](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/blob/f5dd6ae20d0e266f456777828349b76f0b19ab81/R/ggplotly.R#L703-L706). However, this is a workaround you can use.

As the ggplotly function can handle aesthetics from the `geom_line` function, an easy way to fix this is to remove the Y lines and just add some manually specified horizontal lines, as below using the `geom_hline` function:

```
plot <- ggplot(Data, aes(Datum)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept =c(200, 220, 240, 260), size = 0.5, colour = "grey", linetype = "dotted") +
  geom_line(aes(y = Index, colour = "Index"), size = 0.5, alpha = 0.5) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = Long, colour = "Long"), size = 0.5, alpha = 0.5) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,300,20)) + 
  ylab("") +
  xlab("") +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank())

plot <- ggplotly(plot)
print(plot)
```

[image]

Check out [here](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_abline.html) for more documentation on the geom_line functions.

Instead of manually specifying the steps, you can add to automatically determine the line spacing by finding the maximum and minimum y values then creating a sequence:

```
min.plot <- roundUP(min(Data$Index,Data$Long),10) - 20
max.plot <- max(Data$Index,Data$Long) + 20
y.axis <- seq(from = min.plot, to = max.plot, by = 10)
```

and edit the `geom_hline` argument to:

```
geom_hline(yintercept = y.axis, size = 0.5, colour = "grey", linetype = "dotted")
```

Comment: This works, thanks. But it reduces the flexibility because I need to define the position of the lines. I was able to adjust this a little bit by creating a sequence starting with 0 and ending with max + 20. This at least allows me to easily add several lines: `max <- max(Data$Index) + 20` + `y.axis <- seq(from = 0, to = max, by = 20)` and `geom_hline(yintercept = y.axis, size = 0.25, colour = "grey", linetype = "dotted")`

Comment: Yeah good idea. Feel free to add this to the answer as an edit.